# Reorder geom_col outside and with position = "dodge2"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a bar plot using `geom_col()` but am having trouble reordering the columns.

My goal is to reorder to columns such that TEST is reordered such that the largest value overall within each TEST dictates the order of TEST, and then within that test the individual VERSION is ordered from largest to smallest.

for example I want TEST E to be at the top due to VERSION G2 being the largest value overall, and then within TEST D the order is G2, H3 and F1.

So in this, case the overall order of TEST should be: E, B, D, C and A. And then within each test the order should be as following.

E should be: G2, H3, F1
B should be: G2, H3, F1
D should be: G2, H3, F1
C should be: H3, G2, F1
A should be: G2, H3, F1

My code is as follows:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

dat <- data.frame(TEST = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 3),
                  VERSION = paste0(LETTERS[6:8], 1:3),
                  VALUE = round(runif(15, 1, 10), 1))

dat |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = VALUE, y = TEST, fill = VERSION)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge2")
```

[image]

I have tried using `ggplot(aes(x = VALUE, y = reorder(TEST, VALUE), fill = VERSION))` but this doesn't give what I want.

I suspect that there is perhaps a `facet_wrap()` solution but I would like to avoid creating facets due to the increasing size of the resulting plot.

<sup>Created on 2023-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Your stated desired ordering does not match with the data you have created, as is obvious on your plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty is that the dodging order is determined by the factor order of the grouping variable. You have a single fill variable (VERSION) that is also the grouping factor. You cannot easily dodge this differently at each point on your axis. The solution is to have sneaky continuous axes within sneaky facets. This does *not* mean making your plot larger. In fact, it looks like a single plot, just with your bars in the desired order:

```r
dat |> 
  group_by(TEST) |>
  arrange(TEST, VALUE) |>
  mutate(pos = row_number()) |>
  ungroup() |>
  mutate(TEST = fct_reorder(TEST, -VALUE, .fun = min)) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = VALUE, y = pos, fill = VERSION)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge2", orientation = 'y') +
  scale_y_continuous('TEST', breaks = 2, labels = NULL) +
  facet_grid(TEST~., scales = 'free_y', switch = 'y') +
  theme(panel.spacing.y = unit(0, 'mm'),
        strip.placement = 'outside',
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0))
```

[image]